# How can I use ransack with case params[:order] on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in ruby and rails and I user ransack for searching in my web. Since I add case params[:order] in my index. My ransack searching is not working now. I wonder is there anyone can give me some good advise, Thanks here is my index [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCtKX.png)

Comment: you could use `sort_link` or your params[:order] should valid `sort field + order`, reference:  https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Sorting-in-the-Controller

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include code as text. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)